# How to get value of checkbox plus another value together from ejs with express

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

in the code below, I want to get checkbox value `'on/undefined'` based on user selection and the value which I am passing `(item._id)` together in `req.body`. how do I do that?

```
 <form action="/update" method="POST">
                <div class="items">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="<%= item._id%>" onChange=" this.form.submit()">
                    <p><%= item.title %></p>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: first of all `this.form.submit` doesn't seem right , second ,you want to get the checkbox value in fornt-end or back-end ? if front end , you and get it by `myCheckboxElement.value` , if in back-end you need to have a form handling nad validating in express and nodeJS , getting value of checkbox by it's name in `req` parameter in express , you may want to have some libraries like `body-parser` and etc to parse your form

Comment: Buddy. Read the question correctly. See the tags as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer : Pass the additional attribute as hidden property.